# Conditionally showing a placeholder when there is no value in the data ( ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I have a json file that contains images and I am passing them to the front end by mapping the data. When all the items have an image, everything looks great. But if the image is missing, responsiveness breaks and it just doesn't look quite right. So, I would like to display a placeholder in place of "missing photo"

Here's a mini version of my data.json file

```
exports.administration = [
    {
        id:'1',
        image: '/assets/images/media/christopher-walken.jpg',
        name: "Christopher Walken",
    },
    {
        id:'2',
        image: '',
        name: "Jane Doe",
    },
    {
        id:'3',
        image: '/assets/images/media/keanu-reeves.jpg',
        name: "Keanu Reeves",
    },
];
```

And here is my JSX file

```
class Administration extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
            //showImage: true, 
       };
    }

    handleImage = () => this.setState({
       //if there is no image in the data, show the placeholder.png
    });

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {administrationData.map((row, index) => (
                    <Card className="custom-card">
                        <CardText>
                            <Row>
                                <Col xs={12} sm={3}>
                                    { //this the condition I looking for// this.state.showImage
                                    ?
                                        <img style={styles.image} src={row.image} alt={row.name} />
                                    :
                                        <img src='/assets/images/placeholder.png' alt="Not Available" />
                                    }
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </CardText>
                    </Card>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Administration;
```

Kind of a newbie in reactJS.

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need the state for the ternary here because you already have a field that tells you if the image is there or not.

I would just do something like:

```
{(row.image !== '') ? Image : Placeholder}
```

Comment: You are using the value of the css image to show the placeholder or the image. Am I reading that right? My images are in the json file, not in my styles

Comment: Whoops I typed the wrong name, I'll fix it, it's supposed to be using `row.image`.

Comment: YESSSSS!! That's it! Thanks a lot my friend! Slowly but surely, I will get the hang of this